# Android client and server sockets

Tags: android, sockets, server, client-server, port

Im working on android studio, and Im trying to connect a server that I made, with no success.I was able to connect the client to the server when the client is my computer succesfully, when I used this code :

```
socket = null;
                    try
                    {
                        Log.e("client", "Attempting to connect to serverrrrrr.");
                        socket = new Socket(hostname, portnumber);
                        Log.e("client", "Connected ! ");
```

when the host name is like : 
`private static final String hostname= "localhost";
private static final int portnumber=55555;`

then, I realised that it is not working when Im trying to connect to the client from the phone, because I need to put a REAL ip address, and not the localhost thing. Therefor, i tried this :

```
private static final String hostname= "10.0.0.1";
private static final int portnumber=55555;
```

with the same code above, and it did not work. It is just staying in the line of : new Socket ...
and its not moving forward and therefore not connected succusfully. what am I doing wrong ?

I also have this piece of code : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

and I did "port forwarding". What else can I do ?

```
01-30 18:16:47.760 16158-16210/com.omer.tictactoemultiplayer W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.0.1 (port 55555): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

server code: `public class Server extends Thread {

```
private static final int portnumber = 55555;

@Override
public void run() {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try {
        Log.e("Server", "Server starting at port number: " + portnumber);
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portnumber);

        while(true)
        {
            // Client connecting.
            Log.e("Server", "Waiting for clients to connect ...");
            Socket socket1 = serverSocket.accept();
            Log.e("Server", "Client one has connected.");

            Socket socket2 = serverSocket.accept();
            Log.e("Server", "Client two has connected.");
            //Send message to the server.1

            BufferedWriter bw1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket1.getOutputStream()));
            bw1.write("found");
            bw1.newLine();
            bw1.flush();

            BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket2.getOutputStream()));
            bw2.write("found");
            bw2.newLine();
            bw2.flush();

            new ServerThread(socket1,socket2).start();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}
`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138851/discussion-on-question-by-levi-omer-android-client-and-server-sockets).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to your pc from phone, then you have to change
    private static final String hostname= "localhost" for

private static final String hostname= your-pc-ip

You can see your ip with command ipconfig in windows, and ifconfig in linux

Comment: I tried this, and as you can see I changed it, and it never worked.

Comment: Where is your server implemented, Windows? a virtual machine?

Comment: In android studio .

Answer (score 0):

If you only changed the host from localhost to the ip of your computer than your java code that runs so nicely on your PC will not do for Android.

As then you have to put internet code in a thread or AsyncTask.

If you do not do that you will have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` clearly visible in the logcat.

Comment: Man , it ison another thread of course. As you can see I said it worked with localhost , but not with my ip. If it worked once, itmeans everything okay except the ip issue. Understood ?

Comment: I found an exception after waiting 3 minutes.  I edited.